# Double Integral with polar substitution?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is the first time I write in this forum so hope I get everything right! I'm trying to resolve this double integral but I'm having trouble with it :/. First thing I thought about was a polar coordinate substitution but then I don't know where do $\rho$ and  $\theta$ vary. Could anybody give me some help? Thank you all!
$$\iint_\omega 2x+x^2+y^2$$ where 
$\omega = \{(x,y)| x>0,y>0,(x^2+y^2)^\frac 32 \le 2xy\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x > 0$ and $y>0$, so we are in the first quadrant: $\theta$ varies between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Since the region is given by $x,y > 0$, $(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2} \le 2xy$, substituting $x = \rho \cos \theta$ and $y = \rho \sin \theta$, we get $0 < \rho \le \sin 2 \theta$.

Therefore,

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\sin 2 \theta} (2\rho \cos \theta + \rho^2)\rho d\rho d\theta$$

Comment: ok i got it, thank you very much. One last thing, shouldn't it be? $$\iint_\omega 2\rho^2+\rho^3 \, d\rho \, d\theta $$ thank you :)